# How to change migration file name? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, database-migration, rails-migrations

I've got an error with the migration file name (it have to be `projects` instead `products`). I've called this: `20170131095212_add_title_to_products.rb` but it contains the correct table inside:

```
class AddReferenceToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_column :projects, :title, :string, length: 512
    end
end
```

How I can change the migration file name correctly? 
Ruby '2.3.0', Rails '4.2.6'.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename filename,

```
20170131095212_add_title_to_projects.rb
```

rename class.

```
AddReferenceToProjects
```

Also you can delete migration and create new.

Comment: When I read this answer, I first thought, "Why doesn't he just delete the migration and start from scratch?" Glad you mentioned it. There's no reasonable need to keep that migration around, as far as I know.